# How can I convince my math teacher?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, education

Ok, so I got an answer wrong on my exam because my teacher says that the function $f(x)=\frac{(x+2)x}{x+2}=x$ but I insist that it isn't defined for x=-2. If it was then $\frac{x}{x}=1$ for all reals and so $\frac{0}{0}=1$. However this doesn't seem to do the trick with my teacher. How can I use the latter fact to prove something outrageous and convince her?

Comment: Ask her what the domains of the functions are. She may be thinking "where both functions are defined."

Comment: Yes, but did you give your teacher the complete picture on the exam? As in, did you say that $f(x) = x$ except when $x = -2$? Otherwise I think you don't have a case.

Comment: More prudent to read the exact text of the exam and the exact text of your answer before excoriating the teacher.

Comment: What exactly was the question? Was it true/false?  What was your answer? How many points did you lose?  You are correct that '' $\frac{(x+2)x}{x+2}$ '' and '' $x$ '' are not the same function, because they have different domains (if no more context or information is given).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\frac00&=\frac{2\times0}{1\times0}=\frac21=2\\\\\\=\frac00&=\frac{3\times0}{1\times0}=\frac31=3\\\\\\\implies2&=3\end{align}$$
**NOPE.**

Comment: Unless you're a physicist, in which case 2 = 3 for extremely large values of 2 and 3.

Comment: Being trained as a physicist, I'm pretty sure we won't treat 2 = 3. We usually only treat expression involving $\pi$ as 1. e.g $2\pi = 1$ in quantum physics and $4\pi = 1$ in electrodynamics.

Comment: @DavidH how come? Please explain (I ask out of curiosity not bad feelings).

Answer (score 13):

Here's an old chestnut, customized for your example
$$\begin{align}
x&=-2\\
x^2&=(-2)^2=4\\
x^2+2x&=4+2x\\
(x+2)x&=2(x+2)\\
\frac{(x+2)x}{x+2}&=2\\
x&=2 &\longleftarrow\text{ OOPS!}
\end{align}$$
but we assumed $x=-2$ in the first line, so `-2 = 2.`

The problem here is going from the line just before to the line labeled OOPS. As you said, you can't conclude
$$
\frac{(x+2)x}{x+2}=x
$$
when the denominator is zero (i.e., when $x=-2$), though to be fair to your teacher the statement above is indeed true if you include the clause *whenever both sides of the equality are defined*, which is perhaps what she was thinking.

Comment: On your second line $x^2=4 \implies x=\pm 2$

Comment: @user80551. Right, but the first line specified that $x$ was $-2$.

Comment: Yeah, but you are going a longer way to prove the same thing. The proof that follows is reducible to $x^2=4\implies x=\pm 2$ on the second line. You could just say that $x^2=4\implies x=+2$ using the second line and achieve the same result.

Comment: If $x^2=4$ then, as you noted, either $x=2$ or $x=-2$. Obviously the value of $x$ cannot simultaneously be $2$ and $-2$. We chose $x=-2$ so it cannot be that $x=2$ and so if the subsequent steps yield $x=2$ we must have made an invalid inference somewhere. It happens that all of the inferences are correct *except* where I "cancelled" the $x+2$ factors to get to the "OOPS!" line.

Answer (score 12):

It depends on how the question was formulated. It is customary in real analysis not to explicitly mention the domain and/or codomain of a function given by a formula. The convention then is that the domain is the largest one for which the formula give well-defined values and the codomain is assumed to be the reals. If that was the case, then it is indeed the case that the function is equal to $x$, meaning for whatever $x$ for which the function is defined, its value is $x$.

If, on the other hand, the question included a domain that contains the number $-2$ then the question is ill-posed and you have a case.

Answer (score 4):

By convention, we assume that the domain of such functions is the larges subset of $\mathbb{R}$ for which the function is defined. So, the domain of $f(x)=x\dfrac{(x+2)}{(x+2)}$ is $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-2\}$. Additionally, for all $x\ne -2$, we can simplify the function to $f(x)=x$. But we still have the domain of this function as $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{-2\}$. You may try asking your teacher whether they think that $f(x)=\dfrac{x+2}{x+2}$ is defined at $x=-2$ or not.

Another thing that might help:

Ask them whether they think the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x^5-x^2+3x-3}{x^3+2x^2-3}$ is defined at $x=1$. If they say no, then tell them that the function is equivalent to $\dfrac{(x^4+x^3+x^2+3)(x-1)}{(x^2+3x+3)(x-1)}$ and so from their line of reasoning, the function should equal $\dfrac67$ at $x=1$.

Answer (score 3):

Division by zero is a domain violation; your function is defined when $x\not = -2$.  The domain of the division operator $(a,b)\mapsto a/b$ is the set of all $(a,b)$ so $b \not= 0$.  You are done here.

She would have to additionally define $f(-2) = -2$; if you use a case-wise definition, then $f(x) = x$ for all $x$.  Otherwise, no mas.